# Why is a terminal semicolon breaking my CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm pretty inexperienced with CSS, but I know from past experimenting (and other threads on SE) that it's best practice to close the final line of a CSS block with a semicolon, although it's technically optional.

ie:

```
p {
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size:16pt;
}
```

as opposed to:

```
p {
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size:16pt
}
```

BUT on the site I'm designing now (a Wordpress template actually), when I add the semicolon to that final line, the browser refuses to acknowledge that instruction AT ALL. But if I leave off the semicolon, it works!

I'm going to assume I'm doing something wrong here, because it should work identically both ways. Any idea what's going on?

As requested, here's a sample of my actual code. It affects the whole stylesheet, so I just grabbed a few blocks at random...

```
.post p
{
    margin-bottom: 2em
}

.footer
{
    width:60%;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 4em
}

#nav-below
{
    background-color: #dde4ec;
    width:100%;
    height:3em;
    padding-top:1em
}

#nav-container
{
    background-color: #fff;
    width:30%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top:1em;
    margin-bottom:2em
}
```

Don't know if this will be any help, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: That CSS works for me.  Could we have the exact CSS code?  (if that is the exact code, I have no idea what's wrong, sorry)

Comment: Going to need a *minimal* test-case including the *final/actual* CSS output supplied to the browser. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a broken WP minimizer or caching issue along the way.

Comment: Weird, is there a CSS parser/minimizer running after you save it. How does your final CSS look on the page source?

Comment: Do you have this online? Can you give us the link please.

Comment: well, it shouldn't be like that, according to http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-syntax/#error-handling it's optional and the rule is not normative

Comment: The font family needs to be in ''. There may also be invalid characters in there. Fix the quotes, minify everything, copy+paste in a very basic text editor(notepad, not the ++ version), delete it from the old place and put it back from notepad via copy+paste. Notepad scraps a lot of things.